# How to access object with "creative" names in scala?

Tags: scala

For example, given

```
object ~ {
   def foo = ???
}
```

How do i access that method?

Neither of those work:

```
~.foo  

`~`.foo
```

With both the compiler complains about "illegal start of simple expression".

And yes, i know i probably shouldn't name classes "~" but both the standard library and some other libraries do, and sometimes you need to work with them.

Added: Looking at [sschaef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527103/130019) i tried

```
 $tilde.foo
```

And that actually works. Not sure if that's intended or just an implementation detail of how those names are translated to JVM-identifiers. And whether that would work in other flavors of scala (e.g. Scala.js)?

I'll leave this open for a bit to see maybe someone chimes in with a more extensive answer.

Comment: "An whether that would work in other flavors of scala (e.g. Scala.js)?" Eh, give me a little credit here :-p Of course that works in other flavors of Scala.

Comment: Is that guaranteed by the language specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to exist only in 2.11:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_102).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
scala> object ~ { def foo = 0 }
defined object $tilde

scala> ~.foo
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
~.foo
 ^
```

In 2.12 it works fine:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_102).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
> object ~ { def foo = 0 }
defined object $tilde
> ~.foo
res0: Int = 0
```

Comment: Interesting. I was indeed trying on 2.11.8.